# How to add a column in a file whose values are equivalent to epoch conversion of one of the date colmn already in that file using unix commands?

Tags: shell, datetime, unix, unix-timestamp, dos2unix

Suppose I have a .txt file in my unix database : events.txt with 3 columns and 4 records as follow:

```
Name     DateofBirth                           City
Alex     2016-02-22 15:12:21.244000            London
John     2016-02-24 15:12:21.244000            Paris
Harry    2016-02-23 16:17:21.254000            Moscow
Karry    2016-02-23 11:12:21.271000            Berlin
```

I want to edit this table or create a new table which must contain a 4th column named as DOB_epoch (as epoch value of 2nd column DateofBirth) as follow:

```
Name     DateofBirth                           City       DOB_epoch
Alex     2016-02-22 15:12:21.244000            London     9632587410
John     2016-02-24 15:12:21.244000            Paris      9871236540
Harry    2016-02-23 16:17:21.254000            Moscow     9478523690
Karry    2016-02-23 11:12:21.271000            Berlin     9321456870
```

What should be the command in unix to create such table column?

Comment: What are your column separators? Is it tabs? Or does the file have fixed width columns? Assuming you have GNU awk, see https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Time-Functions.html#Time-Functions

Comment: `/me` is staggered that you need to record time of birth right down to the millisecond!

Answer (score 0):

Quite easy with a "while" loop.
Assuming you want to generate an "events2.txt" file :

**For Linux :**

```
#!/bin/bash

while read line;
do
    timedate=`echo $line | egrep -o "20.*[0-9]" | cut -d '.' -f 1`
    if [[ $timedate ]]
    then
        timestamp=`date -d"$timedate" +%s`
        echo -e "$line\t$timestamp" >> events2.txt
    else
        echo -e "$line\tDOB_epoch" >> events2.txt
    fi
done < events.txt
```

**For BSD, just replace the timestamp line with :**

```
timestamp=`date -j -f "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S" "$timedate" +%s`
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it fairly simply in a short shell script using `read`, `date` and `printf`. For example:

```
#!/bin/sh

fname=${1:-/dev/stdin}

c=0
while read -r nm dt tm ci; do
    [ "$c" -eq '0' ] && {
        printf "%-8s %-30s %-10s DOB_epoch\n" "$nm" "$dt" "$tm"
        c=1
        continue
    }
    epoch=$(date -d "${dt} ${tm}" +%s)
    printf "%-8s %-30s %-10s %s\n" "$nm" "$dt $tm" "$ci" "$epoch"
done < "$fname"
```

**Usage/Output**

```
$ sh epochbd.sh dat/epochbd.txt
Name     DateofBirth                    City       DOB_epoch
Alex     2016-02-22 15:12:21.244000     London     1456175541
John     2016-02-24 15:12:21.244000     Paris      1456348341
Harry    2016-02-23 16:17:21.254000     Moscow     1456265841
Karry    2016-02-23 11:12:21.271000     Berlin     1456247541
```

I didn't count characters for spacing, so you may need to adjust the `printf` field-width modifiers by a character or two. Check to make sure your version of `read` supports the `-r` options (otherwise, remove it).